# Can't get Modernizr to load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, modernizr

I'm sure this is something daft, but for the life of me cannot find a simple solution. 
I'm new to using Modernizr and wanted to do a little cross browser testing to utilise its detection of support for svg's, but I can't get the thing to load!
Any help would be great...

[link to working example](http://www.universalphysique.co.uk/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US" class="no-js">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: So it's not adding the classes to the HTML tag? check with `Firebug` or equivalent debugger to see if it's actually loading the file.

Comment: Well for one thing you should load Modernizr **before** jQuery.

Comment: @Pointy, can you explain why?  Regardless, I do that without issue.

Comment: Looks like whatever version of modernizr you generated is broken somehow, it's not injecting the classes into the head tag.

Comment: Well, by its nature Modernizr sort-of prepares the page environment. I guess jQuery is pretty bulletproof, and it doesn't really do anything to the environment (other than its own initialization), so that's probably OK.  It's just a habit I've gotten fanatical about :)

Comment: @NickR yes it seems to be loading fine, and there aren't any errors, but it's just not doing anything.

Comment: Try generating another version from their site and see if that works.

Comment: The best advice I can give is to try a non minified version, and if that doesn't work, trace from the start to see where the execution fails.  I also think Pointy's suggestion is worth a try, in that the two preceding scripts might mess it up somehow.

Comment: @DanielGimenez Tried a non-minified version and rearranged my JQuery and Modernizer tags...still no joy

Comment: Cheers for the input @Pointy

Comment: Cheers @NickR, still no luck though

Comment: This is the development version but minified - http://pastebin.com/8h0j6mxr does this work at all for you?

Comment: @NickR funny you should say that, I just tried the dev version and it worked. The issue seems to be with the production version that has my specific requests??? I downloaded the production version from a couple of different browsers for arguments sake and still no joy

Comment: @SamHolguin Just checking - when you're generating the production version, you were checking the checkboxes for the various different tests, right? :)

Comment: @NickR haha.......yes! I'm a beginner, but come on!! I just used Safari and it worked, bizarre! Cheers for the help Nick

Comment: @Pointy Yes, modernizr should be the first script on the page in the head, and all others (including jQuery) at the bottom of the page just before the closing body tag as best practices, best performance, and user experience.

Comment: BTW, you have a script tag after the closing body tag, which isn't valid.

Comment: @RobertMcKee thank you, I have now amended the position